# Is it possible to create an OnClickListener that will handle both ToggleButton and Switch

Tags: android

I am working on an app that needs to be compatible with pre Android 4.0 devices.

In the pre 4.0 layout I have to use a `ToggleButton` and in the post 4.0 am using a `Switch`. Both function the same as far as the user is concerned. When they are clicked, they should have the same behavior.

I'm trying to write an `OnClickListener` that will work for both of them so that I'm not duplicating a lot of code. The `Switch`/`ToggleButtons` are used inside a `Fragment`, so just placing the call to the `onClickListener` in the layout won't work.

In an effort to try it, for both the `Switch` and `ToggleButton`, I set the `onClickListener` to pushSelector, which is:

```
private View.OnClickListener pushSelector = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked() || ((Switch) v).isChecked()) {
                // code
            } else {
                // code
            }
        }
    };
```

Unsurprisingly, this didn't work, but I thought I'd give it a go.

Is it possible to have a single `onClickListener` that can handle both a `ToggleButton` and `Switch`, or will I need to set up an `onClickListener` for each one?

Comment: use switch case to check selected view by comparing it with isinstanceof()

Comment: not a very good practice but you can do it by implementing click listener for ToggleButton and pragmatically handle state of these controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [a OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) instead, as both Switches and ToggleButtons extend from CompoundButton.

Be aware that if you call (button).setChecked(boolean) from your code, this callback is also called! If you need to set whether or not your button is checked from code, do something like this:

```
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
button.setChecked(boolean);
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mButtonChangeListener);
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks.